# Calculating CAC with weighted Laspeyres index

Tags: weighted-data

I am trying to figure out the best approach to accurately measure customer acquisition cost (CAC) performances for multiple acquisition types when I only have one total spend. To better visualize:

**May (Base Month)**

- Spend = 50,000 dollars
- Phone Leads = 14
- Chat Leads = 164
- Phone CAC = 50,000/14 = 3,571.43 CAC
- Chat CAC = 50,000/150 = 333.33
- Total CAC = 50,000/164 = 304.87

**June (Current Month)**

- Spend = 60,000 dollars
- Phone Leads = 48
- Chat Leads = 133
- Phone CAC = 60,000/48 = 1,250.00 CAC
- Chat CAC = 60,000/133 = 451.13 CAC
- Total CAC = 50,000/164 = 331.49

Unfortunately calculating individual CAC's for Phone and Chat is ineffective and not a good representation of how each acquisition type is performing. As a result I was using the Weighted Laspeyres Index formula to get a better picture of what is happening Month over month, but using Leads and CAC as my two variables. Are these valid variables to use?

Resulting formula example:

```
Phone Price Index (May) = (Base CAC * Base Phone Leads)/(Base CAC * Base Phone Leads)
                        = (3,571.43 * 14)/(3,571.43 * 14) 
                        = 1.0 (Price relative) 
                        = 1.0 * 100 
                        = 100 (Price Index)

Phone Price Index (June) = (Current CAC * Base Phone Leads)/(Base CAC * Base Phone Leads)
                         = (1,250 * 48)/(3,571.43 * 14) 
                         = 0.4 (Price relative) 
                         = 0.4 *100 
                         = 35 (Price Index)
```

Is this the correct formula as well?

Comment: Is this a question about statsitics / ML? If so, can you clarify that aspect? It seems like a business question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I thought this would be related to statistics because of the model being used. If you strip our the business related values, I'm trying to figure out how to measure the changes of multiple variables (how something is acquired) when they are related to one variable (spend). This might be confusing, but the best way I was trying to describe it outside of the business sense.